# sitecore publishing initializing

Tags: sitecore

I get a issue when i want to publish one item in sitecore backend. the publishing popup window freezing and the message shows "Initializing".

I already try to recycle the website application pool, but the issue still there.

sitecore version is 6.3.

And here are some logs:

Exception: System.Exception
Message: Invalid column name 'Sequence'.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderReader..ctor(DataProviderCommand command)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.d__0`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Data.Eventing.SqlEventQueue.GetTimestampForLastProcessing()
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventQueue.GetQueuedEvents(String targetInstanceName)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventQueue.ProcessEvents(Action`2 handler)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseQueuedEvents()
   at Sitecore.Services.AlarmClock.Heartbeat_Beat(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.DataException
Message: Error executing SQL command:  SELECT MAX([Created]), MAX([Sequence]) FROM [EventQueue]

Any help, thanks.

Comment: Have you recently upgraded from another Sitecore version? Looks like your EventQueue table is incomplete. I could tell you how to recreate it, but if this is the result of an upgrade, there are probably a lot more things wrong.

Comment: Thanks for update. i'm not sure about that, but i already checked the sitecore.kernal dll, it's sitecore 6.3 version. do you mean we miss something update in sitecore database when we updated to version 6.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I think you missed some stuff during an upgrade to 6.3.
So there might be a lot of other things wrong, except this EventQueue table, but to fix this table issue you can recreate it:

First drop the EventQueues table in every Sitecore database (core, master and web).

Then recreate it with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE [EventQueue]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [EventType] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [InstanceType] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [InstanceData] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [InstanceName] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    [RaiseLocally] INT NOT NULL,
    [RaiseGlobally] INT NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    [Sequence] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] DATETIME NOT NULL
)
ON [PRIMARY];

ALTER TABLE [EventQueue]
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_EventQueue_Created]
DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE())
FOR [Created]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Sequence] ON [dbo].[EventQueue] ([Created] ASC,[Sequence] ASC)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

If you're lucky, this was the only problem and you're good to go. If you're unlucky, the EventQueue problem will be fixed, but the next problem will pop up :)