# Sitecore publishing stuck initializing 6.4

Tags: iis, sitecore, sitecore6

I am facing issue while doing the publishing site/publishing content in sitecore. The publishing window always stuck at initializing.

**Sitecore Version**: Sitecore 6.4 (rev. 110720)
**Log Error i am getting**: 
WARN  Long running operation: renderContentEditor pipeline[id={FBD9E5F6-D571-487F-BA27-2B95E9F51022}]
This id in the log is the current item ID on which i am doing the publishing.

For all item in sitecore i getting this same issue.
I already restart the IIS and recycle the App-pool.

Please suggest me any answer for this issue.

Regards,
Deepak Narwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while back I have collected together links to a few blog posts, as well as my own investigation, of some of the reasons you might have this issue:

https://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/sitecore-publishing-stuck-on-initializing-after-applying-scalability-settings/

Similar questions are on SO here that may help you investigate:

- [Sitecore Site/Item Publishing hangs at Initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352460/sitecore-site-item-publishing-hangs-at-initializing)
- [sitecore publishing initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471591/sitecore-publishing-initializing)

Comment: Thanks Mark and Jay, i will try your suggestion and update you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following three database tables in the `Master` database. If they have more than a few hundred entries, clear the tables:

- History
- EventQueue
- PublishQueue

After you do that, recycle the authoring instance's app pool and try again.